# I have an error while i hit npm install --force of npm i

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, material-ui

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16 || ^17 || ^18" from @headlessui/react@1.7.15
npm WARN node_modules/@headlessui/react
npm WARN   @headlessui/react@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=18.0" from @react-three/drei@9.50.5
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/drei
npm WARN   @react-three/drei@"9.50" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=18.0" from @react-three/fiber@8.9.2
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN   @react-three/fiber@"8.9" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (@react-spring/three, @react-three/drei)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=18.0" from @react-three/fiber@8.9.2
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN   @react-three/fiber@"8.9" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (@react-spring/three, @react-three/drei)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/next
npm WARN   next@"12.2.5" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17" from react-hook-form@6.15.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-hook-form
npm WARN   react-hook-form@"6.15.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from react-query@3.39.3
npm WARN node_modules/react-query
npm WARN   react-query@"^3.39.3" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=18.0.0" from react-simple-typewriter@5.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-simple-typewriter
npm WARN   react-simple-typewriter@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=16" from react-toastify@9.1.3
npm WARN node_modules/react-toastify
npm WARN   react-toastify@"^9.1.2" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   24 more (@headlessui/react, @react-spring/animated, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=16.8.0" from use-debounce@10.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/use-debounce
npm WARN   use-debounce@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   1 more (react-icons)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16 || ^17 || ^18" from @headlessui/react@1.7.15
npm WARN node_modules/@headlessui/react
npm WARN   @headlessui/react@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional react-dom@">=18.0" from @react-three/drei@9.50.5
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/drei
npm WARN   @react-three/drei@"9.50" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional react-dom@">=18.0" from @react-three/fiber@8.9.2
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN   @react-three/fiber@"8.9" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (@react-spring/three, @react-three/drei)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional react-dom@">=18.0" from @react-three/fiber@8.9.2
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN   @react-three/fiber@"8.9" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (@react-spring/three, @react-three/drei)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/next
npm WARN   next@"12.2.5" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@">=18.0.0" from react-simple-typewriter@5.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-simple-typewriter
npm WARN   react-simple-typewriter@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@headlessui/react, @react-three/drei, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@">=16" from react-toastify@9.1.3
npm WARN node_modules/react-toastify
npm WARN   react-toastify@"^9.1.2" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm WARN node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason:
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   requiredBy: 'node_modules/@material-ui/core'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T13_11_02_556Z-debug-0.log
```

this is the error i found

**NODE version i am using is 20.11.0 **

let me provide you with the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-divjoy-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [
    "divjoy"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@analytics/google-analytics": "0.2.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@react-three/drei": "9.50",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.9",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "1.11.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "1.35.6",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "analytics": "0.3.1",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "query-string": "6.13.8",
    "raw-body": "2.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "6.15.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.2",
    "stripe": "8.132.0",
    "use-debounce": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "stripe-webhook": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/stripe-webhook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

i've tried npm i, npm i --force, removing package-lock.json, again cloning the complete project, npm install, npm cache clean --force, etc but in vail

Comment: This looks like a network issue of some kind - can you access `https://registry.npmjs.org/react` through a browser/Curl on this machine?

Comment: Hey, seems like your `package.json` file is messed up with version mismatches between different packages. You specified the `next.js` version to `12.2.5` while using the latest version of `react`. There may be some more version mismatches with other packages that are dependent each other. For example, some packages may be dependent on older `react` versions while others are on newer versions. You'll have to check different versions of the packages that you added, and adjust the version numbers appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are alright!

I think you need to set your proxy configuration. You can follow the below steps.

- Set the Proxy Configuration.

```
    npm config set proxy http://proxy-server-url:port
    npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server-url:port
```

If you're using an HTTPS proxy, replace `http` with `https` in the https-proxy URL.

- Set Strict-SSL to false. (if needed)

```
    npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

- Set No-Proxy (if needed)

```
    npm config set no-proxy localhost,127.0.0.1
```

- You can check the Configuration.

```
    npm config list
```

- Retry installation.

```
    npm install
```

Hope it helps you. Good luck!